# listar publicaciones wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo que listar las publicaciones de wordpress de manera ordenada, y busco que se listen en el celular de la siguiente forma gráfica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no logro hacerlo, he usado plugins y codigo php pero no logro hacer que queden de esa forma cuando se ven en el celular, logro el efecto pero en forma normal de sitio web, como puedo hacer para que al ser movil el aspecto tenga el deseado. 
de antemano muchas gracias.

no listo videos, sino la imagen destacada de los posts. es un ejemplo eso.
uso post list designer, pero pasa con cualquier plugin.

tengo incluso un código PHP que los lista como deseo, pero no tienen un aspecto muy agradable y en la version movil se descompensa.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    // Second Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
    <?php
    // Second Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
                <!-- <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2> -->
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,300 , true)); ?>
                <!--<p class="caption"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>-->

    <?php endwhile;
    ?>
   <?php
      // Reset Second Loop Post Data
      wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php  endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: buen día, estas usando algún plugin el cual trae la playlist de YouTube?, si es así deber leer muy bien la documentación de YouTube API, tal vez en la forma del Plugin. Por favor, como se llama el plugin y así explorarlo.

Comment: pues bueno, ahora uso post list designer, pero cualquiera me fuciona igual, no traigo lista de videos de youtube, me refiero a la imagen destacada de cada posts.

incluso tengo un código que uso para listarlos, pero al pasar a la versión mobil, no quedan con el mismo aspecto. me gustaria hacer que las imagenes tuvieran un tamaño en pantalla normal y el texto a la derecha y al verlo en movil, la imagen sea mas pequeña pero el texto siga estando a la derecha.

Comment: bueno he logrado avanzar un poco, encontré una función en Wordpress llamada wp_is_mobile() y esta me permite usar un tamaño de imagen thumbnail si es mobil o una Large en caso de no serlo.